# how do ggboxplot with same width

Tags: r, width, boxplot

My problem is that for day 0, I end up with a boxplot twice as wide as the others (because for spores the result is 0).

If I don't put a log scale, I don't have this problem anymore.
But I want to keep the log scale.

*Can you help me?*

This is my data:

[image]`

This is my script:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

result<-read.csv2("essai.csv",sep=",")
result

ggboxplot(result,x="day",y="cfu",fill="condition")+scale_y_log10(limits = c(10^1, 10^6), breaks = 10^(0:6))+
  labs(title = "", x = "day", y = "CFU")+scale_fill_manual(values=c("spore"="gray","total"="gray50"))
```

This is my graph:

[image]

Comment: I can't use the fonction: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html